# Java - MenuBar moves on top of JFrame when setting look and feel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, menubar

When I set the look and feel my AWT MenuBar is displayed on top of the JFrame, this doesn't happen when I use Nimbus or Synth.

The reason I cannot use a JMenuBar is that the application that I am making is a loader for the MMORPG RuneScape which is a AWT Applet, since AWT has priority over swing the MenuBar drop down menu's are hidden by the applet.

I except this is because I'm mixing AWT and Swing components but I don't see any other choice.

Here are a couple of images to help further explain my problems

MenuBar: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/64681860/Code%20Images/MenuBar.PNG

JMenuBar: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/64681860/Code%20Images/JMenuBar.PNG

The Look and Feel I'm using is Substance - BusinessBlackSteel, these problems however also occur with other L&F's such as Metal

I'm hoping someone may have a solution to one of the problems (MenuBar on top of frame, JMenu hidden under applet)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would suspect that *"The reason I cannot use a JMenuBar is that the application that I am making is a loader for the MMORPG RuneScape which is a AWT Applet, since AWT has priority over swing the MenuBar drop down menu's are hidden by the applet.*" would actually answer question.  The short answer is, don't mix heavy and light weight components.

Comment: You need to make popup menus heavyweight.  `JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false); ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);`

Comment: I have no choice, as the Game is awt and I cannot change that :/

Comment: @Vulcan I think you mean "heavyweight", but +1 anyway..

Comment: Thank you very much Vulcan, this is Caleb by the way, long time no see, just getting back into programming again :P I'll get on msn/skype when I get a chance.